# Gelfand triples form Brezis book

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

Consider $H$ to be Hilbert space and $V$ to be a Banach space. Assume that $V\subset H$ is a linear subspace that is dense in $H$. Assume that injection $V\subset H$ is continuous. Brezis says: *there is a canonical map $T\colon H^*\to V^*$ that is the restriction to $V$ of continuous linear functionals $\varphi$ on $H$, i.e.,*
$$\langle T\varphi,v\rangle_{V^*\times V}=\langle \varphi,v\rangle_{H^*\times H}.\qquad (1)$$
What stands behind the existance of $T$? Why can we write (1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S:V\to H$ be the inclusion, and set $T=S^*$.  Then for all $\varphi\in H^*$ and all $v\in V$ we have 
$$T\varphi(v)=\varphi(Sv)=\varphi(v),$$
which is precisely $(1)$.